# Python function not recognising global list

Tags: python, list

Ok so I have a program that is going to randomly generate some tuples and add them to a list for use in making a bitmap image.
Problem is that I keep getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/Chill/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 27, in <module>
    nextPixel((pixelList[-1])[0], (pixelList[-1])[1], t,)   File "/Users/Chill/Desktop/Untitled.py", line 23, in nextPixel
    if (i, j) not in pixelList: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pixelList' referenced before assignment [Finished in 0.078s]
```

Here is the code:

```
from random import randint
from PIL import Image

startPixel = (0, 0)
pixelList = [startPixel]
print(pixelList[-1])
print(pixelList[-1][0])
i = j = 0
#Replace 0 with timestamp for seed
t = 0


def nextPixel(i, j, t):
    #Random from seed
    iNew = i + randint(0, 2)
    #Random from -seed
    jNew = j + randint(0, 2)
    if iNew == jNew:
        jNew = (jNew + 1) % 2
    iNew -= 1
    jNew -= 1
    #Checks pixel created does not already exist in the list
    if (iNew, jNew) not in pixelList:
        pixelList += (iNew, jNew)

while pixelList[-1][0] < 255:
    nextPixel((pixelList[-1])[0], (pixelList[-1])[1], t)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: add 'global pixelList' at the start of your nextPixel function. that king of programming is not usually considered very elegant, though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pixelList` is a list of tuples, and that the `nextPixel` function is mean to append a new tuple to it. However, the line:

```
    pixelList += (iNew, jNew)
```

is actually attempting to *concatenate* the the new tuple and the list. This won't work, because the augnmented assignment will treat `pixelList` as a *local* variable (which doesn't exist, resulting in an error).

What you need to do instead is this:

```
    pixelList.append((iNew, jNew))
```